# Simplify expression in Scala

Tags: scala

I have such case classes:

```
abstract class Tree

case class Sum(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree

case class Var(n: String) extends Tree

case class Const(v: Int) extends Tree
```

Now i write such object :

```
object Main {

  type Environment = String => Int

  def derive(t: Tree, v: String): Tree = t match {
    case Sum(l, r) => Sum(derive(l, v), derive(r, v))
    case Var(n) if (v == n) => Const(1)
    case _ => Const(0)
  }

  def eval(t: Tree, env: Environment): Int = t match {
    case Sum(l, r) => eval(l, env) + eval(r, env)
    case Var(n) => env(n)
    case Const(v) => v
  }

  def simple(t: Tree): Const = t match {
    case Sum(l, r) if (l.isInstanceOf[Const] && r.isInstanceOf[Const]) => Const(l.asInstanceOf[Const].v + r.asInstanceOf[Const].v)
    case Sum(l, r) if (l.isInstanceOf[Sum] && r.isInstanceOf[Sum]) => Const(simple(l).v+ simple(r).v)
    case Sum(l, r) if (l.isInstanceOf[Sum]) => Const(simple(l).v + r.asInstanceOf[Const].v)
    case Sum(l, r) if (r.isInstanceOf[Sum]) => Const(simple(r).v + l.asInstanceOf[Const].v)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val exp: Tree = Sum(Sum(Var("x"), Var("x")), Sum(Const(7), Var("y")))
    val env: Environment = {
      case "x" => 5
      case "y" => 7
    }
    println("Expression: " + exp)
    println("Evaluation with x=5, y=7: " + eval(exp, env))
    println("Derivative relative to x:\n " + derive(exp, "x"))
    println("Derivative relative to y:\n " + derive(exp, "y"))
    println("Simplified expression:\n" + simple(derive(exp, "x")))
  }


}
```

I am new in scala. Is it possible write method `simple` with small count of code and maybe in scala way?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there. In Scala, extractors can be nested:

```
def simple(t: Tree): Const = t match {
  case Sum(Const(v1), Const(v2)) => Const(v1 + v2)
  case Sum(s1 @ Sum(_,_), s2 @ Sum(_, _)) => Const(simple(s1).v+ simple(s2).v)
  case Sum(s @ Sum(_, _), Const(v)) => Const(simple(s).v + v)
  case Sum(Const(v), s @ Sum(_, _)) => Const(simple(s).v + v)
}
```

Of course, this will give you some warnings about incomplete matches, and the sx @ Sum(_, _) repeatedly suggests that there may be a better approach that includes matching on Const and Var at the root level and making more recursive calls to simple.

Comment: Thanks. @ is smthing like isInstanceOf?

Comment: Kris will know better than me but I think it's more like "this pattern which we'll match after the @ will be assigned to the val using the name given before."

Comment: @ is used to name the value matched by the pattern.  s @ Sum(_,_) matches with Sum's extractor and binds s to the Sum if it succeeds.

Comment: Both of the above answers are correct; I would phrase it pretty much how naten did.

Comment: In which language constractions is it possible to use extractors?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been closed, but I think this version should be a better one,

```
def simplify(t: Tree): Tree = t match {
    case Sum(Const(v1), Const(v2)) => Const(v1 + v2)
    case Sum(Const(v1), Sum(Const(v2), rr)) => simplify(Sum(Const(v1 + v2), simplify(rr)))
    case Sum(l, Const(v)) => simplify(Sum(Const(v), simplify(l)))
    case Sum(l, Sum(Const(v), rr)) => simplify(Sum(Const(v), simplify(Sum(l, rr))))
    case Sum(Sum(ll, lr), r) => simplify(Sum(ll, simplify(Sum(lr, r))))
    case Sum(Var(n), r) => Sum(simplify(r), Var(n))
    case _ => t
}
```

it seems works with "complex" expressions with variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small improvement:

```
def derive(t: Tree, v: String): Tree = t match {
    case Sum(l, r) => Sum(derive(l, v), derive(r, v))
    case Var(`v`) => Const(1)
    case _ => Const(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def simplify(t: Tree): Tree = t match {
    case Sum(Const(v1),Const(v2)) => Const(v1+v2)
    case Sum(left,right) => simplify(Sum(simplify(left),simplify(right)))
    case _ => t //Not necessary, but for completeness
}
```

Note that it returns a Tree, not a Const, so it should be able to simplify trees with variables too.

I'm learning Scala so any suggestions as to why this wouldn't work etc. are more than welcome :-)

---

EDIT: Just discovered that the second case causes an infinite loop when using variables. Substitute it with:

```
case Sum(left,right) => Sum(simplify(left),simplify(right))
```

Unfortunately this breaks when `left` and `right` return Const, which could be simplified even further (e.g. `Sum(Const(2),Const(3))`).